# UIView changes orientation with ugly corners

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, orientation

I have several small views with some background on the screen. When i change orientation of the device my viewcontroller animates that. The problem is that during the animation views have really ugly corners.

Comment: Can you include any detail? Screenshots? A better description than "ugly"?

Comment: There is a video of same rotating http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/

Comment: The code is simple, tableview with my cells, cells have subviews, subviews have background, everything works good except the animation

Comment: Er, that's a massive blog post about image resizing. What does that have to do with your question?

Comment: There is the video of the rotating image. I have the same problem with the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to set radius for the corners, using the following:

1. You should firstly add `QuartzCore.framework`
2. add the header `#import<QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`
3. use this piece of code: `(v for view)`.

   ```
   [v.layer setCornerRadius:30.0f];
   [v.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor];
   [v.layer setBorderWidth:1.5f];
   [v.layer setShadowColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
   [v.layer setShadowOpacity:0.8];
   [v.layer setShadowRadius:3.0];
   [v.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(2.0, 2.0)];
   ```

Hope that help you.

Comment: Followed all steps. But this code draws circle on the view, and doesn't help while rotating,  i will try to try something with border color and width , thanks

Comment: Try add this line `label.layer.masksToBounds = YES;`

Comment: Thanks ))) really worked for me!)))) I do not understand how, but worked)))!  backgroundView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;